# selecting the maximum bids overall

Tags: sql, database

I have User table as follows:

```
Userid| Username |city| state
```

here userid is the primary key
and there is a bidding table

```
Userid|seller|iid|starttime|bidtime|bidprice
```

here userid,seller,iid form the primary key

I want to write an sql query so that userid and name of the person who made most bids overall will be displayed. I wrote the query as follows:

```
select u.userid,u.uname from user1 u, bid b where u.userid=b.bidder and
b.bidder=(select max(c) from (select count(*) as c, bidder from bid group by bidder));
```

but in this case the inner select is displaying the maximum value which doesnot satisfy the given condition. I want some help to how to approach this problem

Comment: Posting some sample data and the desired result would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select userid, uname from user1 
where userid in 
(select bidder from bid group by bidder having count(bidder) = 
(select max(c) from (select count(*) as c, bidder from bid group by bidder)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to be a simpler way to accomplish that.

```
SELECT TOP 1 u.*
FROM User1 u
JOIN bid b ON (u.userid=b.bidder)
ORDER BY Count(b.*)
```

Comment: use `u.userid=b.bidder` instead of `u.bidder=b.bidder`

Comment: That's why it is a good idea to tag your question with your database platform.